# Factory function: why doesn't status variable change to "OK"?

Tags: javascript, function, factory

I'm switching from javascript classes to factory functions. 
Besides arguments, I need internal properties, eg. status in the below simplified example. So, why is status not set to OK and how should it be done?

```
const Model = (name) => {
    name = "myname";
    let status = "initial";

    const setOK = () => {
        status = "OK";
    }
    return {name, status, setOK}
};

const m = Model();
console.log(m.status); //status is initial
m.setOK();
console.log(m.status);  //expecting OK, but still initial
```

Comment: the `status` in the returned object gets its initial value from `let status`, but changing the value of `let status` doesn't change the object returned

Comment: *"... to not uses classes and use factory functions. I was just looking for the "best" way to get this done. "* See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55086917/2813224) on object composition

Comment: Thanks CertainPerformance and zer00ne, you both helped a lot and pointed me to the right direction. I’ll have to dive a bit more into it and play with these concepts first before the big refactor:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Object Composition](https://medium.com/code-monkey/object-composition-in-javascript-2f9b9077b5e6)

Use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge objects or *"inherit"* methods without using `class` or `prototype`.  [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
/* 
Object monitor has setOK() method. 
Note the parenthesis wrapped around the curly braces ensures
that the object literal will be invoked as a expression.
The props object from Model is passed to monitor object
*/
const monitor = props => ({
  setOK: () => {
    props.status = "OK";
  }
});

/* Factory Function 
Note the object literal props. props will be passed through
Object.assign() method in order to inherit the method setOK() from the monitor object.
*/
const Model = name => {
  let props = {
    name: name,
    status: "initial"
  };
  return Object.assign(props, monitor(props));
};

// Create object m with the name: "checkStatus"
const m = Model("checkStatus");
// Verify object m is named "checkStatus"
console.log('name: '+m.name);
// Check status
console.log('status: '+m.status);
// Invoke .setOK() method
m.setOK();
// Check status
console.log('status: '+m.status);
```

Comment: HI zer00ne, thanks for this. Seems a bit more flexible in terms of reusability. I think I need to let this sink in. Until now I've just used "plain" functions, In my real code I  need a lot of other internal properties besides the status, so I'll have a look on how to get it done.

Comment: Hi @WU7 the first link is a very good article, it enlightened me -- I was using only functions as well (nothing wrong with that though). Once I got a grasp of object composition, I began to understand OOP concepts like classical inheritance and prototypes better as well. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the object that is returned never changes: your

```
return {name, status, setOK}
```

returns an object with those three properties, with the values *as they were when the object was returned*. If you want the object to change, instead define the object beforehand inside of `Model`, and mutate said object inside of `setOK`:

```js
const Model = (name) => {
  name = "myname";
  let status = "initial";
  const setOK = () => {
    obj.status = "OK";
  };
  const obj = { name, status, setOK };
  return obj;
};

const m = Model();
console.log(m.status);
m.setOK();
console.log(m.status);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So if I get this right, I need to build an object within my factory function and return this object. Is this the way factory functions are created using the => functions?

Comment: Not here - in this code, it doesn't make any difference to use an arrow function vs a standard `function() {`, because the calling context (`this`) is never checked or assigned to.

Comment: I see. Before I start to refactor my code, is there any better way to do this? I mean future wise I've read, to not uses classes and use factory functions. I was just looking for the "best" way to get this done.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with classes - in fact, I would prefer them, if possible. They work just fine, and are often a bit easier to read: https://jsfiddle.net/7smhp9ru/

Comment: that's so true and I had my program working fine with classes for a small part I started to refactor... but then I read this [link](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e)
After which I started to read about factory functions... and then it got a bit more complex:-)